# Primefaces new line in confirm message

Tags: primefaces

Helllo, I have a problem and here I do not find function solution.

I have .properties file `confirmClone=Bla bla bla`

and this code

```
<p:confirm header="Confirm" message="#{msg.confirmClone} #{msg.confirmNextText}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
```

I use primefaces 6.1.

What I nedd to add, if I want empty line between `msg.confirmClone` and `msg.confirmNextText` ?

Comment: You can always actually add a new line, and use a CSS rule to pre-format the white-space. Have not tried this, but did you try adding a `<br/>`?

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```xml
<p:confirm header="Confirm"
           escape="false"
           message="#{msg.confirmClone} &lt;br/&gt; #{msg.confirmNextText}" 
           icon="ui-icon-alert" />
```